# Can I import existing .Rnw Sweave file into LyX?

Tags: lyx, sweave

I am trying to import an existing Sweave `.Rnw` file into LyX. I wonder whether LyX is capable of doing it? My LyX version is 2.02 and I can use its Sweave module with no problem. I find out it does have an import Sweave option but I cannot import the simplest `.Rnw` file like the one below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\author{ZZ}

\begin{document}
\title{Simple}
\maketitle
\section{Simple Examples}
A simple example:
<<>>=
N <- 5
N
@
\end{document}
```

When I try to import this file, it gives me the following error message:

```
An error occurred while running:
Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore
"/Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/scripts/lyxsweave.R"
"/Volumes/COMMON/Documents/""addone.Rnw"
"/Volumes/COMMON/Documents/""addone.tex"
"/Volumes/COMMON/Documents/"
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Shall I do it differently?

Comment: given the number of up votes. I think this question should not be closed.